# The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly in janus

Tags: c#, janus

I'm Using a Janus v2 trail in my project. When run the project, I get this exception:

> The invoked member is not supported in a dynamic assembly

in this line:

```
this.btnInvoice = new Janus.Windows.EditControls.UIButton();
```

Can you help me with this?

Comment: are you using asp.net?

Comment: no,I'm  only Using  C#.